# Using key tool to make a CSR, how do I make a cert for tomcat ssl?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, exception, certificate, keytool

My objective is to use keytool to create a certificate signing request (CSR), then take that CSR and make an actual cert to add to the keystore, add it, such that SSL (HTTPS//my.site.com) will work.  This is for testing purposes.

So far I have done the following steps:

1. Generate a keystore for my CSR:

   keytool -genkey -dname "CN=test.com, OU=TEST, O=Test, L=TestCity, ST=Florida, C=US" -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore test.keystore -storepass changeit
2. Generate the CSR:

   keytool -certreq -alias tomcat -file request.csr -keystore test.keystore -storepass changeit
3. Generate a server key to use with openSSL to create a signed cert.  This required a password "changeit" and then a conversion to remove the password for the server.key:

   openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048

   cp server.key server.key.org

   openssl rsa -in server.key.org -out server.key
4. Generate my signed cert using the CSR:

   openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in request.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
5. Finally, import the cert into my keystore.

   keytool -import -trustcacerts -file server.crt -keystore test.keystore -alias tomcat -storepass changeit

The result is the following error:

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match

Answer (score 0):

> `keytool -genkey -dname "CN=test.com, OU=TEST, O=Test, L=TestCity, ST=Florida, C=US" -alias tomcat`

This does more than generating a key pair, it also generates a self-signed certificate with this DN, which is then used as a basis to generate a CSR with `-certreq` (it may sound odd, but a self-signed cert and a PKCS#10 CSR are actually very similar: the CSR is more or less a self-signed cert without the validity timestamps).

This is in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_genkeypair):

> `-genkeypair`
>
> [...]
>
> Generates a key pair (a public key and associated
>   private key). Wraps the public key into an X.509 v3 self-signed
>   certificate, which is stored as a single-element certificate chain.
>   This certificate chain and the private key are stored in a new
>   keystore entry identified by alias.
>
> [...] This command was named -genkey in earlier releases.

What you would normally do when submitting the CSR to a CA is re-import the cert issued by the CA into the same alias (where your private key is), thereby overwriting that temporary self-signed certificate.

You can skip the steps with `keytool -certreq` and `openssl`: simply export the certificate with `keytool`, and re-import it a separate truststore to use with your Java clients if necessary.

---

If you want to simulate a CA, `openssl x509` is not the command you should use:

> openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in request.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt

As the [documentation for `openssl x509 -signkey`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html) states:

> `-signkey filename`
>
> this option causes the input file to be self signed using the supplied private key.
>
> If the input file is a certificate it sets the issuer name to the subject name (i.e. makes it self signed) changes the public key to the
>   supplied value and changes the start and end dates. The start date is
>   set to the current time and the end date is set to a value determined
>   by the -days option. Any certificate extensions are retained unless
>   the -clrext option is supplied.
>
> **If the input is a certificate request then a self signed certificate is created using the supplied private key using the
>   subject name in the request.**

So, essentially, the public key material also comes from this private key. Hence, it will not match the public key in the CSR you provided. The CSR is only used to provide the certificate identity information and attributes in this case.

Indeed, turning a CSR into a certificate is something that can have many parameters. While `keytool` generates a reasonable default self-signed certificate from the parameters you provide, OpenSSL generally requires a bit more configuration. For what you're trying to do, [`openssl ca`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ca.html) would certainly be more relevant, although I would suggest using the [`CA.pl`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/CA.pl.html) wrapper for convenience (it will keep track of the certificates you've issued, serial numbers, and so on).

Since this seems to be mainly for testing, possibly on an occasional basis, you may also find other tools like [xca](http://xca.sourceforge.net/) to be more convenient to perform that step.

Comment: I do not want to skip that step.  This is a simulation on how it would really work.  I want to develop an automated processes.  The end user will get a CSR that we will generate.  Then they will send it to a real CA to get a signed cert to import.  So I want to generate a signed cert to simulate that.  If I simply skip that part, then the test is no longer valid.   I need to generate a cert from the CSR that I can then import / overwrite using the keytool that operates in the same manner as it would if it was being created by a real CA.

Comment: From what you're doing, you seem to want to use `server.key` as a CA signing key, which doesn't quite make sense if it's the server key (for which I'm not sure you have a cert).

Comment: I just did that because I was googling how to generate a cert from a CSR and that was the only example I found.  If you read the first paragraph, that describes what I want to do.  Take a CSR, create a cert from it, then apply that cert to my keystore such that SSL connections will work.   My main issue when googling this is that all of the articles are on how to create a CSR and not on how to create a usable cert from the CSR. I do not really know what the server key is for, other than it is required for the openssl signing step.

Comment: I am trying to write a tool that will work via a web interface that will allow a customer to create a CSR, then when they get their cert from the CA, I can apply the cert to the box so they can use a branded URL.  Now I need to actually be able to test this system, so I need to create a snakeoil cert from the CSR so I can then feed into my system just so I can see if it all works.

Comment: You *can* use `openssl x509 -req` with `-CA` and `-CAkey` to specify a CA key *and cert* -- both are needed; this does not have all the features of `openssl ca` but it does the basic job. Also, `openssl ca` by itself keeps track of serials and issued certs; `CA.pl` "merely" fills in some "standard" flags and filenames so you don't have to think about them (but that "merely" can save time and avoid mistakes).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the following is right, but it seems to work.  Cobbling some steps together from various web sites, executing these commands generate a keystore that works for SSL connections via tomcat.  It does it pieces parts which will let me test each piece of my system.

1. Generate the keystore

> keytool -genkey -dname "CN=test.com, OU=TEST, O=Test, L=TestCity, ST=Florida, C=US" -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore test.keystore -storepass changeit

2. Generate the CSR

> keytool -certreq -alias tomcat -file request.csr -keystore test.keystore -storepass changeit

3. Export the private key from my keystore for use in creating a signed cert

> keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore test.keystore -srcalias tomcat -destkeystore myp12file.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
>
> openssl pkcs12 -in myp12file.p12 -out server.key

4. Create the signed cert from the CSR

> openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in request.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt

5. Finally import it to the keystore, with success

> keytool -import -trustcacerts -file server.crt -keystore test.keystore -alias tomcat -storepass changeit

Comment: I suppose that can be a suitable workaround for tests, but that certainly doesn't simulate the process you're implementing: by giving you their PKCS#12 file, your users give you far more than the CSR, they give you their private key as well. This is something they should never have to do.

Comment: Uses will not be giving me their PKCS#12 file.  This, again, is for testing.  The real workflow will be that they will use a web interface to get a CSR which they can download.  They will take it to a CA, and then they will give us the cert the CA provides, through a web interface,  which I will add to the keystore.  There will be no private keys being sent out, nor will anyone get access to the keystore file.  I just need a way to locally test this code without getting real certs from a real CA.

Comment: Sure, I got that, it's just it doesn't seem like a very realistic test this way, since your test requires more than what would be given to you in practice. Using a CA tool (e.g. `openssl ca`, `CA.pl`, ...) as I've added in my answer earlier would give you something probably more realistic for what you're trying to simulate.

Comment: Thanks for your help though.  Id give you an upvote or something, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that.  I will look into those tools.

Comment: In addition to teaching insecure behavior, this complicated process produces a self-signed cert, just like that one that `keytool` created in the very first step. If you want to test installing a cert that *can be verified* against a CA (like a real one) you need something that creates a CA-issued cert, for which @Bruno's suggestion of `CA.pl` or `openssl ca` is a good option though not the only possible one.

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure describes the creation of a JKS keystore that works perfectly with JBoss 5.0 application server. Tomcat probably uses the same type of keystore.

#### Create private key and *Certificate Signing Request*

You can create a private key in a Linux OS with the help of openssl utility.

Set umask to 077 so that the created file is only readable by the current user:

> ```
> $ OLD_UMASK=`umask`   (umask is inside backtick characters)
> $ umask 077
> ```

Create a private key of 2048 bits length  and store it in file `private_key.pem`:

> ```
> $ openssl genrsa 2048 > private_key.pem
> ```

Restore the file creation mask:

> ```
> $ umask $OLD_MASK
> ```

You can create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) with the command:

> ```
> $ openssl req -new -key private_key.pem -nodes
> ```

Next you will have to answer various questions. Give special attention to the *Common Name* field that must match the *Fully Qualified Domain Name* of your server. The command generates the following text that comprises the CSR:

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
>
> MIIBZYnPGQZK06tI6EKLGp7qmaFAIAe ...
>
> ....
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

#### Generate a chain certificate

The procedure assumes that you have a (a) private key in file `private_key.pem`, (b) a digital certificate that you have received from a Certificate Authority (CA) in file `certificate.pem` and (c) a chain certificate that certifies the CA in file `ca_chain_cert.pem`.

In case that your CA is certified by another authority CA1 that is finally certified by a root CA CA_ROOT (CA -> CA1 -> CA_ROOT) and the respective certificates are available in individual files `ca_cert.pem`, `ca1_cert.pem` and `ca_root.pem` respectively, you can create the `ca_chain_cert.pem` through the command:

> ```
> $ cat ca_cert.pem ca1_cert.pem ca_root.pem > ca_chain_cert.pem
> ```

The chain certificate is generated by combining `certificate.pem` with the `ca_chain_cert.pem`:

> ```
> $ cat certificate.pem ca_chain_cert.pem > chain.pem
> ```

The concept is that you must have a file that includes all certificates with the order:

1. host certificate
2. CA certificate
3. CA1 certificate
4. root CA certificate

#### Generate the JKS keystore

This step assumes that file `chain.pem` includes the chain of certificates ,`private_key.pem` the private key and `certificate.pem` the server certificate that you received from the CA (first part of the chain).

Create a PKCS12 keystore in file `keystore.p12` from the certificate chain and the private key with the following command:

> $ openssl pkcs12 -export -name server_cert -in chain.pem -inkey private_key.pem -certfile certificate.pem -out keystore.p12

Write down the *Export password* as it will be used in all the following steps to have access to the keystore.

Create a JKS keystore in file `server.keystore` from the PKCS12 keystore:

> $ keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore server.keystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -alias server_cert

You can list the certificates with the following command:

> $ keytool -list -v -keystore server.keystore

Verify that the command output states the correct size of the certificate chain. In the case of CA, CA1 and CA_ROOT the size must be 4.